# in hmvc How to load a controller from another controller in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

Call controller inside a controller in *codeigniter hmvc* me call my controller like

```
$this->load->controller('controllername','',TRUE);
```

Comment: does "caliing a controller from another controller" follow good MVC standards?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a controller from another controller
Please See [Load Controller within Another Controller in Codeigniter](http://www.techsirius.com/2013/01/load-controller-within-another.html) you wil need to follow this tutorial.

Comment: @AtulSunil Glad i could help! would appreciate if you could mark and vote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Put it on a helper or create another base class on which the two other classes can extend from.

Comment: fixed it modify MY_Loader in core folder, thNX for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
   $this->asign_any_variable= modules::load('module_name/controller_name/');
```

**Example below:**

```
    $this->subscription = modules::load('subscription/subscription/');


    //set $return to FALSE. It will print the view
    $return = FALSE;
    $this->subscription->subscription_group($return);
```